# PHP Time Difference Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Mike C for the help. The database was structured under EndTime instead of endTime.

--

I know this may be asked several times - I have read several tutorials and I get errors. Would love some help!

I have two times in a MySQL database. I'm trying to take the time difference from time2 to time1 to display to the client in `hours:minutes:seconds` format. Both times in the database are `DateTime` format.

I have a Live Timer (taking time1 from server time) that displays in the web page if the closingTime variable isn't complete. The If statement works fine. Once we have a Time1 and Time2 time established on the page the page will load a time but it's the current snapshot of the StartTime difference from the server time.

[image]

In the picture above, the left is a live javascript timer and the right is just taking a snapshot instead of displaying the time difference  between startTime and COGtime

**Variables: (from DateTime in MySQL)**

```
$startTime = $row['startTime'];
$COGTime = $row['endTime'];
```

**If only startTime is entered: (Working time on left side of image)**

```
echo '<div id="StartTimeFromServer"></div>';
```

**If both StartTime and endTime are entered: (BROKEN: currently right side of image.. should take COGTime - startTime)**

```
                        $date_a = new DateTime($startTime);
                        $date_b = new DateTime($COGTime);

                        $interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);

                        echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

**Counter JS Script**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
  function CountUp(initDate, id){
      this.beginDate = new Date(initDate);
      this.countainer = document.getElementById(id);
      this.numOfDays = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];
      this.borrowed = 0, this.years = 0, this.months = 0, this.days = 0;
      this.hours = 0, this.minutes = 0, this.seconds = 0;
      this.updateNumOfDays();
      this.updateCounter();
  }

  CountUp.prototype.updateNumOfDays=function(){
      var dateNow = new Date();
      var currYear = dateNow.getFullYear();
      if ( (currYear % 4 == 0 && currYear % 100 != 0 ) || currYear % 400 == 0 ) {
          this.numOfDays[1] = 29;
      }
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function(){self.updateNumOfDays();}, (new Date((currYear+1), 1, 2) - dateNow));
  }

  CountUp.prototype.datePartDiff=function(then, now, MAX){
      var diff = now - then - this.borrowed;
      this.borrowed = 0;
      if ( diff > -1 ) return diff;
      this.borrowed = 1;
      return (MAX + diff);
  }

  CountUp.prototype.calculate=function(){
      var currDate = new Date();
      var prevDate = this.beginDate;
      this.seconds = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getSeconds(), currDate.getSeconds(), 60);
      this.minutes = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getMinutes(), currDate.getMinutes(), 60);
      this.hours = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getHours(), currDate.getHours(), 24);
      this.days = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getDate(), currDate.getDate(), this.numOfDays[currDate.getMonth()]);
      this.months = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getMonth(), currDate.getMonth(), 12);
      this.years = this.datePartDiff(prevDate.getFullYear(), currDate.getFullYear(),0);
  }

  CountUp.prototype.addLeadingZero=function(value){
      return value < 10 ? ("0" + value) : value;
  }

  CountUp.prototype.formatTime=function(){
      this.seconds = this.addLeadingZero(this.seconds);
      this.minutes = this.addLeadingZero(this.minutes);
      this.hours = this.addLeadingZero(this.hours);
  }

  CountUp.prototype.updateCounter=function(){
      this.calculate();
      this.formatTime();
      this.countainer.innerHTML ="" + this.hours + "" + (this.hours == 1? ":" : ":") + "" +
          "" + this.minutes + "" + (this.minutes == 1? ":" : ":") + "" +
          "" + this.seconds + "" + (this.seconds == 1? "" : "") + "";
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function(){self.updateCounter();}, 1000);
  }

  window.onload=function(){ 
                            new CountUp('<?php echo $startTime // downtime start from db ?>', 'StartTimeFromServer'); }
  </script>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @MikeC I have updated my question. I hope this has a better understanding.

Comment: Have you verified that `$date_a` and `$date_b` are the correct values? Also, I don't see where in your Javascript you're using the time difference. I only see `$startTime`.

Comment: Have you tried testing with hardcoded values

Comment: @MikeC echoing the $startTime gives value 2016-08-21 22:58:00, turns out the database was structured under EndTime instead of endTime. Thank you.